# How to tell if a kinesis stream is not being processed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis

When processing an AWS Kinesis stream, how to tell if a consumer is no longer processing the stream? Is there a metric in Kinesis that I can use for alarming for example?

There is a metric for [IteratorAgeMilliseconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch.html) however, this metric is only written when a stream is being processed. So in case a consumer is down and the stream is backing up with messages, we would know that this happened only when we resume processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GetRecords.Bytes` to determine whether the stream is being read.

If you have only one consumer, you could use [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html) to compare it with `PutRecords.Bytes` and/or `PutRecord.Bytes`. With more than one consumer you'd need to divide the gets by the number of consumers, and if you have a variable number of consumers that isn't going to work.

You could also enable [anomaly detection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create_Anomaly_Detection_Alarm.html) on the stream. I haven't done this, so can't tell you how well it works.

But the approach that I prefer (and have used successfully multiple times) is to *have your consumer write a custom metric,* such as the number of records that it's processed. Then you can set up an alarm on the consumer not reporting that metric.